# Stop automatically scanning for Wi-Fi on Linux Mint

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint

How can I disable the automatic scan for other Wi-Fi networks when I'm already connected on Linux Mint? I have an HP laptop with touchscreen buttons and the Wi-Fi button doesn't act as usual. It always blinks because the system is always scanning for other networks. For an example, it acts normally on Windows 7 but I guess there are no good drivers for Linux. Anyway, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong, both Windows and Linux always scan networks in background.

What is different is how the LED is handled, for example on my laptop (Atheros AR9284 card) the LED doesn't light up at all in Windows, but always stays lit in Linux and a `/sys/class/leds/ath9k-phy0` LED device is created.

In my case, the `/sys/class/leds/ath9k-phy0/brightness` file contains 255, I can `echo 0` to it to turn off the LED :

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/ath9k-phy0/brightness
```

You should be able to do the same (of course the `ath9k-phy0` name may vary) and if that works, just put the command somewhere where it'll get executed on each boot.

Comment: @DimitarNikolov I suggest you take a look at the "trigger" file in the same directory, that will allow you to put that LED to good use like making it blink on network usage, firewall usage, CPU load, etc.